# Boundary of cone in $ \mathbb{R} ^3$

Tags: general-topology

Is $z^2=x^2+y^2$ where $-4\leq z \leq 4$ a cone that has no interior? What is the boundary of that cone? Is it the cone itself since it does not have any interior? I am somewhat familiar with boundary overall, but in 3D and with things other than spheres, I get a bit confused.

Comment: The inequality -4 < z < 4 imposes a kind of "cap" on either end of the double-cone; the boundary of this surface is then composed of three pieces: a portion of the cone itself, and two circular caps on either end. The interior is all of the points within either sub-cone

Comment: Oh wait, I misunderstood; you're talking about just the *surface* of the cone as its own manifold. In that case, the cone inherits the relative topology from $\mathbb R^3$ which is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$ at any point not on the boundary. In this case, the boundary is the two rim-like circles, and the 'interior' is the rest of the surface of the cone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S:=\{(x,y,z): z^2=x^2+y^2, z \in [-4,4]\}.$

It is easy to see, that $S$ is closed and $S^°= \emptyset.$ Hence

$$ \partial S= \overline{S} \setminus S^°=S.$$